# Failing to load VSC live server javascript error

Tags: visual-studio

When I am using Live server loading HTML it comes up with:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by going to XAMPP and turning on Apache.